# How to avoid N+1 queries for primary entities, when using Custom DTO Object

Tags: spring, hibernate

Have a simple DTO Object as follows,

```
@BatchSize(size=100)
public class ProductDto {

    @BatchSize(size=100)
    private Product product;

    private UUID storeId;
    private String storeName;

    public ProductDto(Product product, UUID storeId, String storeName) {
        super();
        this.product = product;
        this.storeId = storeId;
        this.storeName = storeName;
    }
    // setters and getters ...
}
```

Have Spring Data Repository as follows,

```
public interface ProductRepository extends CrudRepository<Product, java.util.UUID>
{    
    @BatchSize(size=100)
    @Query("SELECT new com.app1.dto.ProductDto(c, r1.storeName, r1.id) "
        + "FROM Product c left outer join c.storeRef r1")
    public Page<ProductDto> findProductList_withDTO(Pageable pageable);
}
```

When the code runs, it executes one SQL for loading Product ID and StoreName and StoreId

```
SELECT product0_.id AS col_0_0_,store1_.store_name AS col_1_0_,
   store1_.id AS col_2_0_ FROM Product product0_
   LEFT OUTER JOIN Store store1_ LIMIT 10
```

But the problem is next line,

For each Product Row that exists in Database, it's executing SQL Query, instead of using IN to batch load all matching Products in 1 SQL.

For each products it executes following,

```
 SELECT product0_.id AS id1_20_0_, product0_.prd_name AS prd_nam15_20_0_ FROM Product product0_ WHERE product0_.id = ?
 SELECT product0_.id AS id1_20_0_, product0_.prd_name AS prd_nam15_20_0_ FROM Product product0_ WHERE product0_.id = ?
```

**Question,**

How can we inform hibernate to load all Product Rows in Single SQL Query? I have tried adding @BatchSize(size=100) at all places. Still it's executing multiple queries to load Product Data.

Any hints/solution will be appreciated.

Thanks
 Mark

Comment: Can you please try again without using LEFT OUTER JOIN in your query and updating the results on the question? Thanks!